# On AWS, is it possible to find leftover data on the instance stores or EBS volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Say, I create a great many new EC2 instances and inspect a great many instance stores and EBS volumes. Is it possible to find data leftover on the instance stores or EBS volumes from a previous user?

I am not imagining that I will find files or directories; however, I wonder if AWS zeros out the drives between uses.

Comment: Well multiple users are sharing the same hardware.  If it's possible under reasonable means to see old user's data that would be a security issue.

Comment: that's why snapshot does the job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no currently published exploit.

Here are some previous exploits:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/how-secure-are-virtual-machines-really-false-sense-of-security
- http://www.contextis.com/resources/blog/dirty-disks-raise-new-questions-about-cloud/
- http://insights.wired.com/profiles/blogs/think-server-based-vdi-keeps-your-data-secure-think-again